# Quick Launch Menu - open in new window/tab - foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, quick-launch

I'm trying to set the quick launch menu links to open in new window. I'm using Sharepoint foundation 2013. Since it's asp menu i tried to add Target="_blank" property. But it still opens in the same window.

```
                    <SharePoint:AspMenu
                    id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    runat="server"
                    Target="_blank"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                    UseSimpleRendering="true"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="3"
                    AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                    SkipLinkText=""
                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

The following JS function is adding to the div above the global and local navigation, and it causes the target to be ignored:

```
onclick="return AjaxNavigate$OnClickHook(event, this);"
```

You can disable MDS (minimal download strategy) or use jQuery to remove onlick event.

```
$("div[id*='V4QuickLaunchMenu'], div[id*='TopNavigationMenu']").removeAttr("onclick")
```

Please read the following article: http://www.siolon.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-site-navigation-does-not-open-in-new-window/

Comment: Foundation doesn't have settings for navigation so i put the target property into the master page and it seems that deactivating MDS changed nothing. It still opens in the same window.